How to retrieve all data connections of tabular models on a SSAS instance?
I write you because I have a SSAS instance with many models deployed. I need to extract the information about data connections of all tabular models.
To make an example:  I have three models, A, B, C. Model A has two connections, the first one towards an Oracle DB and the second one towards an Excel File. Model B has a connection towards a txt file. Model C has a connection to a Mongo database. I need a query to run on the whole instance and, for each model, retrieve the above information about the connections.
I know that with DVM it's possible to query some system tables, but I don't know if it's the most correct way.
Does anyone could help me?
Thanks.

When you mentioned the DMV, you are in the correct way and this section explains the Rowsets described in the [MS-SSAS-T]: SQL Server Analysis Services Tabular Protocol :
SELECT 
    DB_NAME([Database_ID]) AS [ModelName],
    DS.[DataSource_Name] AS [ConnectionName],
    DS.[ConnectionString] AS [ConnectionString],
    DS.[DataSource_Type] AS [DataSourceType]
FROM 
    $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_DATA_SOURCES DS
JOIN 
    $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_MODEL M 
    ON DS.[Model_ID] = M.[ID]
ORDER BY 
    [ModelName], [ConnectionName]

